# jqgrid column return type and return format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

Can any one tell me what is return type of jqgrid column(s) and in which format it returns?
In my project am using jqgrid (am new to jquery and jqgrid). please help me. I want to save the column order in database.

Advanced Thanks.